# Dynamic include expression require_once($filename) is not analysed

Tags: php

My tree is described as below:

```
src
  Domain
     Customers
        Basic.php
        Premium.php
     Book.php
     Customer.php
     Person.php


<?php
use Bookstore\Domain\Book;
use Bookstore\Domain\Customers\Basic;
use Bookstore\Domain\Customers\Premium;
use Bookstore\Utils\Unique;

function autoloader($className) {
    $lastSlash = strpos($className, '\\') + 1;
    $className = substr($className, $lastSlash);
    $directory = str_replace('\\', '/', $className);
    $fileName = __DIR__ . '/src/' . $directory . '.php';
    require_once($fileName);
}

spl_autoload_register('autoloader');
```

I got this error in browser:

```
require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\firstapp/src/Domain/Book.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\firstapp\init.php on line 15
```

and

```
dynamic include expression require_once($filename) is not analysed on phpstorm
```

What is the problem ?

**EDIT:** this is the init.php file

Comment: is `book.php` or `Book.php` ?

Comment: Book.php every file and directory start with uppercase

Comment: if yoy use this `C:\xampp\htdocs\firstapp/src/Domain/Book.php` work?